# Quote become &quot; on PHPExcel

Tags: phpexcel, utf8-decode

I'm using PHPExcel to export data into excel report. But the below characters are being altered.

```
" become &quot;

& become &amp;
```

Example:

> "The Company" --> become `&quot;`The Company`&quot;`
>
> Me & My Company --> become Me `&amp;` My Company

Can anyone help me on how can I fix it. Thanks!!

Comment: PHPExcel shouldn't be doing this; please show exactly what you're doing with the data before and after

Answer (score 2):

Double-check the strings that you are passing to PHPExcel to make sure that they don't already have the HTML elements in them. Note that if you are debugging by dumping output to your browser then the string in your PHP code may actually already be

`This &amp; That`

but the browser will display it as

`This & That`.

Comment: hi thank you for information. but i have a question, if my data is \" then how could i output it as " only?? i'm using php platform

Comment: The PHP function [stripslashes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) should do the trick.